# Regex con un valor mínimo y un valor máximo

Tags: javascript, regex

tengo un código en el que mediante un regex tengo que verificar que un valor se encuentre entre -50 y 160, pero no termino de comprender del todo como funciona la sintaxis de las regex.
Se me ha ocurrido algo así, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar:

```
(-[5-9][0-9]|[1][6][0])
```

Comment: El escenario, tal cual está descrito, bastaría con un If de validación de -50 a 160. ¿Hay alguna restricción que tengas para usar un regex? Una analogía: Es como usar un cañón para bajarte una mosca.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que separar el problema

-50, del -49 al -1, del 0 al 9, del 10 al 99, 100 al 159 y el 160

```
\b(-?([0-4][0-9])|(-?50)|([0-9])|([0-9][0-9])|(1[0-5][0-9])|(160))\b
```

```js
let regex = /(^(-)([1-4])?[0-9]$)|(^-50$)|(^[1][0-5][0-9]$)|(^160$)|(^[1-9]?\d$)/g

pruebas = ["-60" ,"1", "-2", "3", "-50", "160", "200","-100","-76","170","1000"];

for (let p of pruebas) {
    console.log(p, !(p.match(regex) == null));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer un regex como este:

```
(?<!-|\d)(-50|-49|-48|-47|-46|...|159|160)(?!\d)
```

Es tedioso escribirlo a mano, pero con Javascript lo puedes generar fácilmente.

```js
regex = "(?<!-|\\d)("
for (let i = -50; i < 160; i++)
    regex += i + "|"

regex += "160)(?!\\d)"

prueba = "1 -2 3 -50 160 200 -100"
for (let match of prueba.matchAll(regex))
    console.log(match)
```

---

También puedes simplemente usar un regex para encontrar todos los números que aparezcan, los conviertes a número y haces la comparación:

```js
regex = /-?\d+/mg

prueba = "1 -2 3 -50 160 200 -100"
for (let match of prueba.matchAll(regex)) {
    número = +match
    if (número >= -50 && número<= 160)
        console.log(match)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar esta expresión regular:

```js
function validarNumero(numero) {
  regex = /(?<!-|\d)(-50|-[0-4][0-9]|(160|1[0-5][0-9]|[0-9]?[0-9]))(?!\d)/gm;

  if (regex.test(numero)) {
    // Si el número se encuentra entre los números -50 y 160, retorna true y dirá que es válido.
    return 'Es válido';
  } else {
    // Si el número no se encuentra entre los números -50 y 160, retornará false y dirá que no es válido.
    return 'No es válido';
  }
}

console.log(validarNumero(-51));
console.log(validarNumero(-50));
console.log(validarNumero(-49));
console.log(validarNumero(0));
console.log(validarNumero(161));
console.log(validarNumero(160));
console.log(validarNumero(159));
```